# How to add a checkbox column to dataTables with a check-all header and ajax-paginated data?

Tags: jquery, datatable

This question pertains to [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), version 1.9.4.

I want to make the first column of my data table have a checkbox, same as Gmail and many other apps. In the header row should be another checkbox. When clicking it, it should check the boxes in every row. Flipping to a different page should not uncheck any boxes.

Per some related questions, here's what I've come up with so far:

```
$('#dt_basic').dataTable({
    'sAjaxSource': {{ action('api.permissions')|json_encode|raw }},
    'bDeferRender': true,
    'aoColumns': [
        {
            'sTitle': '<input type="checkbox" id="check-all">',
            'mData': 'id',
            'mRender': function(id) {
                return '<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check['+id+']">';
            },
            'sWidth': '15px',
            'bSortable': false
        },
        {
            'sTitle': 'Code',
            'mData': 'code'
        }
    ],
    'aaSorting': [[0,'asc']],
    'fnDrawCallback': function(oSettings) {
        $('#check-all').prop({'indeterminate':false,'checked':false});
    }
});

$('#check-all').on('change', function() {
    $('#dt_basic').find('.check').prop('checked',this.checked);
});

$('#dt_basic').on('change','.check', function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('#dt_basic').find('.check');
    var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(function() { return this.checked; });
    if($checked.length === 0) {
        $('#check-all').prop({'indeterminate':false,'checked':false});
    } else if($checked.length === $checkboxes.length) {
        $('#check-all').prop({'indeterminate':false,'checked':true});
    } else {
        $('#check-all').prop('indeterminate',true);
    }
});
```

This renders a checkbox in the first column, but they get unchecked if I go to a different page. How can I get dataTables to retain the checkbox state such that when I return to a previous page, they will still be checked, and such that I can get a list of all checked boxes, whether or not they are on the current page?

Checkbox state should also be retained during filtering.

This likely implies that the checkboxes/rows will remain in the DOM but simply become hidden *or* some kind of serialization happens when you change pages. The [description of deferred rendering](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html) says that DOM nodes are retained, but this is not the behaviour I'm observing.

Comment: How about keeping the state in cookie or in HTLM5's `localStorage`?

Comment: Have you considered using $_SESSION variables? That is what I use for such things in PHP. If you're not using PHP, however, @lesssugar's suggestion is very good

Comment: @khaverim: I don't want to send any data to the server until the user submits it.

Comment: @lesssugar: I don't need long-term storage. Just needs to be retained until they submit the form or navigate away. Storing it in a regular old JavaScript variable would be fine, but I don't want to jump through hoops to work with the DataTables API.

Comment: a page won't retain state when you leave it. localStorage makes the most sense to me. Just store one array/object using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to convert. Then clear the localStorage key on submit success

Comment: @charlietfl Why are you guys having such trouble understanding that I'm not reloading the page? I wrote **ajax**-paginated for a reason.

Comment: `Flipping to a different page` makes it easy to assume is why. You can store the checkbox data on what used to be aData. Not sure what version datatables you are using. API just got majorly changed recently

Comment: datatables does not keep dom nodes in page for paging. It caches html in string but that won't retain property changes like `checked`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid sending data to the server you can use JS-only "session" variables through the `window` object.

e.g.

`window.checked = ['box2','box4'];` and access it again with `window.checked`. Then run the `if` condition to dynamically check the boxes if they exist in `window.checked`.

Also: this is a very useful and lightweight script for such purposes: http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

Using this script you can save a JS "session" object/variable like this:

```
sessvars.checkStates = {box1: "on", box2: "off", box3: "on"}
```

You could make a script to access this object and check each box for "on" and change the checkbox state accordingly

Comment: What you've described are not "session" variables. You've simply created a global variable by defining it on the window object. It's not even necessary to make them global; they can be neatly contained in a closure wrapped around the dataTables code. Unless you have some pointers about how to save and restore the checkbox state by hooking into some kind of paginate event, this isn't very helpful :\

Comment: the script in the link I provided provides a JS object that persists through different pages on your site. You can access it just like a session variable, but the difference is that it's not messing with the server. All is contained to the client in JS.

Comment: The "pages" are done via ajax. I'm not reloading the page. I don't need session vars. Local vars will persist.

Comment: Okay, but this will still do the job you're looking for, unless you want to completely avoid session variables

Comment: Yes, yes I do. Why would I use something I don't need at all?